# JQuery: Comparing date entered in textbox against today's date

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do i make a check whether a date entered in a text box is greater than today's date?   Format retrieved from text box e.g. 14/05/2013

Comment: Format that date to be parseable by `new Date("date string")`, then just compare with `>` against `new Date()`

Comment: Have you tryed something?

Answer (score -1):

```
var entered_date = $("#txtBox1").val();    
var today = new Date();
if(entered_date>today)
{
   //...
}
```